# Why are my lines getting automatically simplified in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: line, arcgis, digitization

I painstakingly am following a complex, windy road, drawing aline, and when I finsh the line, it automaticlaly simplifies to ugly, angular lines that are way off from the original road. how do I stop it from doing this?

If it matters, there are also grids on my map that I cant get rid of either.

I repeatedly tried to digitize the line, but every time this happens.

Comment: Does anybody know how to change this?